# Genesis: How can headline of post title

Tags: wordpress, genesis

I use Genesis framework, and i need to change headline from H1 to H2

for example i need to change from :

```
<h1 class="entry-title" itemprop="headline"><a href="..." rel="bookmark">....</a></h1>
```

To :

```
<h2 class="entry-title" itemprop="headline"><a href="..." rel="bookmark">....</a></h2>
```

Comment: I'd suggest a child theme and/or a filter.

Comment: i dont understand you

Comment: child theme: https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes. Filter: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_filter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your active theme's `functions.php` add the following code:

```
function my_title_wrap(){
    return 'h2';
}
add_filter( 'genesis_entry_title_wrap', 'my_title_wrap' );
```

This will change h1 tag to h2 for `entry_title`.

If you need to change headline tags other than `entry_title` just search where that tag coming from. In Notepad++, Search->Find in Files can help you to search for particular term in Genesis files. Find the filter used to output that tag and use that filter to change it as demonstrated in the above code.